# laravel - I try to delete row out of a table from the database with a href icon

Tags: laravel, controller, crud, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

So what I'm trying to do is delete a row from my database table with a icon button (href)

```
<a href='notstarted/delete/{{$task->idtask}}' style="color: #8B0000"><span title="Delete Task"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span></a>
```

Here is my controller

```
    public function destroy($idtask) {
    DB::delete('delete from tasks where idtask = ?',[$idtask]);

    return redirect('/todo/notstarted');
}
```

and here is my routing:

```
Route::get('notstarted/delete/{idtask}','NotstartedController@destroy');
```

so my button is on page /todo/notstarted , when i click it it goes to /todo/notstarted/delete/1 like I want but it shows the laravel 404|Not Found page. Normally the redirect in my controller should work but for some reason it broke.

here is a picture of my folder structure of my views:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wf3Mw.png)

Hopefully someone can help!

Comment: Change `<a href='notstarted/delete/{{$task->idtask}}'` to `<a href='/notstarted/delete/{{$task->idtask}}'`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is your anchor tag's href
you should use laravel url() helper.

like the code below :

```
<a href="{{url('notstarted/delete/',$task->idtask)}}" style="color: #8B0000">
   <span title="Delete Task"><i class="far fa-trash-alt"></i></span>
</a>
```